# Удалять первый нажатый символ

Tags: javascript

Есть поле ввода телефона по маске  `+7(___) ___-__-__` , иногда пользователь начинает вводить вторую цифру 8 и тогда номер записывается неккоректный. Как можно не печать первый символ, если это 8 ?

**Решил задачу:**

```
function getCaretPos(input) {
    if (input.createTextRange) {
        var range = document.selection.createRange.duplicate();
        range.moveStart('character', -input.value.length);
        return range.text.length;
    } else {
        return input.selectionStart;
      }
}

$(".personal-phone").on("keydown", function(e){
  var val = $(this).val();
  var char  = e.keyCode;
  var pos = getCaretPos(this);
  if (char == 104 && pos == 3) {
       e.preventDefault();
  }

 });
```

Comment: А если он введет вторую цифру 7? А все остальные?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Я бы хотел понять принцип, а проверку на остальные символы уже сам бы доделал.

Comment: Ставите обработчики событий keypress, проверяете какая цифра набрана, в какой позиции. Если не нравится - отменяете событие. Как будто никто ничего не нажимал на клавиатуре. Посмотрите урок https://learn.javascript.ru/keyboard-events Там есть пример отмены ввода

Comment: А 8 - нормальная первая цифра. Номера всяких бесплатных служб 8-800-1234567, +7-800-1234567. Хотите и себе такой номер сделайте на ближайшей телефонной станции за отдельную плату. Зря взялись номера телефонов проверять. Без знания плана нумерации ошибок не избежать в принципе. А планы они такие, что могут и поменяться со временем. http://www.rossvyaz.ru/activity/num_resurs/registerNum/ (Там например нет спутниковых номеров, которые на 500, если не ошибаюсь).

Comment: @Sergey пробую ваш метод, как найти позицию текущей цифры?

Comment: `target.selectionStart`, `target.selectionEnd` показывают начало и конец выделенного текста в элементе `target`. Кроме того указывают на позицию каретки при вводе (куда будет вставлен символ). В этом случае они равны. Принимают значения от 0 - каретка в начале строки, 1 - после первого символа и т.д. до конца строки

Comment: @Sergey , спасибо! Решил задачу.

Answer (score 1):

почему не используешь функцию [chartAt](http://javascript.ru/string/charat) ?

`if yourString.charAt(0) == 8 {function deleteFirstStmbol()}`

Comment: потому что уже давно доступно обращение по индексу: `s[0] === s.charAt(0)`

Comment: а как работает функция deleteFirstStmbol() ?

Comment: написал для примера, в зависимости от логики кода ищет и удаляет первый символ в строке. Вот как я реализовал:

`var str = "Вот такая строка";
function deleteFirstStmbol ( string ) {
 return string.slice(0,1);
 }
console.log(deleteFirstStmbol(str));`

Comment: Ваш способ не совсем подходит, решил задачу, добавил описание